# Cannot Like my testpage with the like button

Tags: testing, facebook-like, counter, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-iframe

I have a testing website and i tried out the fb likebutton there. But everytime when i click on the like button, the counter goes firstly to 1 and a second later to a Link with the count 0. The only note from fb debug is that i should check my images, because they should not get bigger than 200px in both dimensions, but its only 100x100px.

What did i do wrong ?

Below there is my code. Thanks for your help.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Timos Testpage" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="author" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://oimel1987.tipido.net/test.php" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://oimel1987.tipido.net/dummy.png">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="oimel1987.tipido.net" />
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="100001556570293" />
  </head>
  <body>
    Test abc
    <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Foimel1987.tipido.net%2Ftest.php&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=150&amp;show_faces=true&amp;font=tahoma&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;action=like&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:150px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Double check the OG data in [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.yasni.de%2Fcrystal_harris%2Fperson_information). Also I am able to like after confirming the action.